# How can I get my UV islands to not be scattered into so many pieces regardless of the unwrap method?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

Please see the attached image. It becomes extremely difficult to paint textures having to deal with so many tiny islands. How can I fix this?

[image: comparison of both unwrap methods]

When I'm texture painting there is a lot of pixelation, so I'm not sure if this small-island-issue is the core cause of that. Please see the attached image:

[image: awful pixelation]

Blend File:
[image]
(all of the images are referencing the shape titled "balcony")

Comment: Well, if you set the margin so high that there is so much between each of them, it is hard to get a lot of islands in the limited area of a UV map...  and maybe you want to set the interpolation mode in the _Image Texture_ node to _Closest_ instead of _Linear_ so that the texture does not get blurred (below the image name in the node).

Comment: It's because of the terrible topology of your model which obviously wasn't created in Blender. You can improve matters slightly if you select All in Edit mode then use Mesh > Clean Up > Limited Dissolve, but you really need to clean it up manually, preferably by modelling it from scratch in Blender, then mark seams on the object and Unwrap it again. As @GordonBrinkmann says, the Island margin is set ridiculously high too! Unwrapping again with your settings also brings up a brief warning saying "Unwrap failed to solve 1 of 1 island(s) edge seams may need to be added".

Comment: @JohnEason Thanks for the input. I recently started modeling in Nomad (an app for the iPad) and I'd unwrap in Blender. I'm not sure if I should stick with this app though- what makes you say the topology of this model is terrible? Again, I'm new to modeling so I don't know a lot about these sorts of things.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to explain simply and here is not really the place, but if you look at the object close up in Edit mode, you'll see that the whole object is made up of triangles and lots of them appear to have their vertices in the middle of an edge. Normally you would model an object like that with all the faces as rectangles which makes the UV unwrapping much more straightforward. You should really follow one of the many online Blender tutorials to see how it should be done.